# First run Intellij+AspectJ ，hava a lot of errors

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to use AspectJ in sample project in IntelliJ IDEA. I have an experience with Spring AOP, but this is first time I am using AspectJ, and cannot make it work.

Environment:Win 10, IntelliJ IDEA and AspectJ,
Refer to this document for configuration,
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/aspectj.html

```
public class Hello {
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("test1.Hello, AspectJ!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.sayHello();
    }
}

public aspect TxAspect {
    void around():call(void Hello.sayHello()){
        System.out.println("Start transaction...");
        proceed();
        System.out.println("end transaction...");
    }
}
```

It should hava outputs:
Start transaction...
Hello, AspectJ!
end transaction...

but it appears a lot of errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqtxB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the jdk release from 10 to 8 can solve this problem.

Comment: I have tried several times, maybe  the latest  AspectJ release could not surpport the Java 10.

Comment: AspectJ [1.9.1 supports Java 10](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-191.html), [1.9.2 supports Java 11](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-192.html). If you used one of these versions and it is not working, probably your IDE or Maven build configuration is wrong.